# Why bother inspecting an uploaded file's content-type if the sender can lie about what it is?

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-5, file-type

I'm writing an API that is hidden behind Azure's API Management tool. It can't be accessed unless APIM verifies the requester's access token as well as Azure subscription. In the API, we want to verify with the requester that we will only accept zip files.

```
if (request.PayloadFile.ContentType != "application/zip")
{
    throw new BadRequestException("Unable to accept payload content type");
}
```

This is **not** a process attempting to mitigate a bad actor. The purpose is to simply verify that the developer is sending the expected data type. With that said, I made a small client that sends a non-zip format file and I simply set the content-type header in the request:

```
var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath));
fileContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/zip");
fileAsFormData.Add(fileContent, "payLoad", fileName: Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

The API happily accepts this. So my question is twofold:

1. Why would we even bother checking `ContentType` if it can be spoofed?
2. Is there a way to get the true file type of the payload?

Comment: First thing on my mind is that it prevents good faith users from upload the wrong file type by accident. zip file format has a magic number in the first bytes, you can check that, but it alone doesn't guarantee that's a valid zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Content-Type is a way for a client to indicate for the server what content you wish to send. Of course you might maliciously "lie" about it, but it would be against your own interest as a client. Servers might implement appropriate logics to parse file content, depending on the Content-Type header.

There are several things to consider:

1. A server is expected to work properly, only if the client sends valid data: i.e.: clients that want the server behave properly should not lie about the real Content-Type of uploaded files.
2. It is easier for servers to check a Content-Type header, compared to specifying file types using other methods.
3. Servers should also validate data and mitigate risks in case of possible misuse of an API. For example, in your case, you should add try-catch around unzipping content, and respond with error if unzipping was not successful.

For your other question, whether real Content-Types can be checked, the answer is generally: no. There are some file types, where the file itself contains some kind of "magic string" that can be used as a signiture for that Content-Type.

You can check some of these common file signitures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Please note that, a malicious user might be able to modify file signatures as well. There can be additional security measures to defend against spoofing file contents, e.g.: checksums, but there is no 100% security, unless some private secret is shared among servers and trusted clients, which can be used to securely sign contents.

The real question here is: why would anyone maliciously spoof Content-Types? Or file contents? And what level of security measure is needed to avoid associated risks?